# Is this how friction is a centripetal force when a car is making a turn?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

[image]

I've been wondering why frictional force acts as a centripetal force when a car is turning; my intuition would not lead me to believe it would act perpendicular to velocity, but I think I have at least somewhat of an image as to why it happens.

Is the diagram I've drawn somewhat correct? Is the x component of frictional force on the front tires the centripetal force? I know the diagram is not that good, I'm just trying to get the intuition for how it works.

Please do correct any errors I may have made. I think there would probably be some other forces I am leaving out.

Comment: No, it tends to be the case that all 4 wheels will have a radial component, that together make up the centripetal force. The centripetal force is what is needed to have something go in a circle; something else must provide it, and in this case, it is friction.

Comment: A more correct drawing would point the rear axis toward the center of rotation. The front wheels turn different amounts so that the axis of each wheel points toward the center of rotation. Manufacturers make steering like this so the tires all oriented int the direction they roll. Tire wear goes way up if they don't.

Answer (score 0):

*my intuition would not lead me to believe it would act perpendicular to velocity*

I'm not sure, but I can guess that your intuition is what is leading you astray.  Because we first learn about *kinetic* friction, we tend to "intuit" that all frictional forces should point "opposite to the motion" in some way or another.  For kinetic friction the statement of the force is very easy:
$$
\vec{F}_{fk} \text{  points opposite to $\vec{v}$ with magnitude $F_{fk} = \mu_k F_N$}\,,
$$
where $\vec{v}$ is the relative velocity of the object with respect to the surface.

But, **for static friction there is no simple statement**, about either the direction or the magnitude. And it is a static frictional force in your problem: static friction acts inward radially on the car's tires (perpendicular to their direction of motion), providing the "centripetal force" necessary to get the centripetal acceleration that keeps the car moving on a circular path.

To see this most easily, draw a free-body diagram of the car as *viewed from behind*.  You will have a normal force upward, gravity downward, and static frictional force inward (leftward based on your picture), with the latter in the same direction as the acceleration vector.

---

So, what is the intuition for static friction? Here are a few things:

- It is, by definition, a force that acts when the surfaces are *not* sliding with respect to each other.  Your tires should not screech when you drive on a circular path, because they are not sliding on the road.  When you run around a corner, you plant your foot and push off to the side.  If your foot slides, you will not make it around the corner.
- Static friction prevents motion of an object.  If you push on a refrigerator and it does not move, it is static friction that acts opposite to your pushing force. In your car example, it is static friction preventing the car from sliding (outward) off the circular path to continue natural straight-line motion.
- Don't try to make up rules for how static friction should point.  There are no rules about its direction with respect to velocity, acceleration, or applied forces.  Just remember it is completely different in this sense than kinetic friction.

One example that I find useful is a book held against a wall.  You can press against the book, such that there is a large normal force of the wall acting outward on the book.  Now angle your force upward, in an attempt to get the book to slide up the wall.  If the book does not slide, it is static friction acting downwards (*opposite* to your tangential force) that prevents motion.  Now slowly lessen your force.  At some point the book will slide down the wall.  But before it does, a static frictional force is acting *upwards* (in the *same* direction as your small tangential force) to keep the book from sliding down.

Answer (score 0):

A non-accelerating wheel is able to roll with minimal force.   So in the ideal case that a car is moving at a constant speed without braking or acceleration from the transmission, the wheel exerts zero force in the rolling direction.

But they strongly resists sideways motion.  So the frictional forces on the car will be perpendicular to the rolling direction of the wheels.

The forces you have drawn in the direction of rolling would only be present if the wheels were being driven.   These forces aren't responsible for turning.

Comment: Does your answer imply that friction is not acting as a centripetal force here? I got confused.

Comment: @BowlOfRed You said because of pure rolling there won't be any rolling friction opposing the velocity and static friction would act perpendicular to the direction of velocity. But can there be a case (no pure rolling), in which there is rolling friction as well (along with static friction acting as centripetal force)?

Comment: @Proscionexium, if the car is moving in a circle, then it is the static friction acting perpendicular to the wheel motion that is providing the necessary acceleration.   In that case it would be the centripetal force.   But the diagram is not correct showing the directions of the forces.

Comment: @PinkAura, I did not use the term "rolling friction", which usually refers to the drag on a rolling object, separate from any static friction.   Yes there can be friction along the direction of motion.   This is exactly what the brakes and the transmission provide.  But in the ideal case, such forces are often ignored in simplified scenarios.